# LINQ Group By Count for Many to Many

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 entities, with a 1 to many relationship, and I'm going to switch it to many to many but I need help with grouping and counts.

SearchString -> many JobResults

A SearchSting is used to find job results and job results are stored as a collection property of SearchString:

```
public class SearchString
{
    public int SearchStringId { get; set; }
    public string SearchStringName { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public JobFunction JobFunction { get; set; }
    public JobSeniority JobSeniority { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobSearchResult> results { get; set; }
}
public class JobSearchResult
{        
    public int JobSearchResultId { get; set; }
    public string jobtitle { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public virtual SearchString SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

I get the top 5 JobFunctions of all job results as follows:

```
var top5jobfunctions = JobSearchResults.Where(a => (a.SearchString != null)).
            GroupBy(s => new { s.SearchString.JobFunction.JobFunctionId, s.SearchString.JobFunction.JobFunctionName }).
            Select(g => new { value = g.Key.JobFunctionId, displayname = g.Key.JobFunctionName, count = g.Count() }).
            OrderByDescending(x => x.count).
            Take(5).ToList();
```

I'm going to switch it to many to many as such:

```
public class SearchString
{
    public int SearchStringId { get; set; }
    public string SearchStringName { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public JobFunction JobFunction { get; set; }
    public JobSeniority JobSeniority { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobSearchResult> results { get; set; }
}
public class JobSearchResult
{        
    public int JobSearchResultId { get; set; }
    public string jobtitle { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SearchString> SearchStrings { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get my top 5 jobfunctions counts once I switch it to many to many?

Also, is the structure I chose the right approach? For example I wonder if having jobresults a child collection of SearchString was maybe not the best way to go and that perhaps I should just have SearchStrings be a collection property of JobResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the modified model with many many relationship, consider the following modification to your original query:

```
var top5jobfunctions = 
  JobSearchResults.SelectMany(j => j.SearchString.Select(s => new {j,s}))
                  .Where(j => (j.s != null))
                  .GroupBy(j => new { j.s.JobFunction.JobFunctionId, j.s.JobFunction.JobFunctionName })
                  .Select(g => new { value = g.Key.JobFunctionId, displayname = g.Key.JobFunctionName, count = g.Count() })
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
                  .Take(5).ToList();
```

**Explanation:**

- Now since `JobSearchResult` contains `ICollection<SearchString>`, it needs flattening to execute a similar query as earlier
- `SelectMany` flattens the data and fills the results as an anonymous type, which contains a record for each `SearchString`
- Henceforth similar logic as you have designed is followed

**Model Correctness**

- I would not prefer, this kind of relationship, as it makes overall querying and data insertion unnecessarily complex
- In my understanding a 1 to Many relationship would do as good a job in fetching all the relevant information, in this case you may consider just having `ICollection<JobSearchResult>` aggregated inside `SearchString` or vice versa relationship based on suitability, I am not sure what kind of use case does a circular many many relationship model solve.

Comment: What's happening is a job is found using a search string, stored under it, and then that same job is also found using another search string, but since it was already added under another search string it gets discarded. The goal is for us to see a job was found under more than one search string. I am thinking it would be better to have just a SearchString collection property of JobSearchResult instead. Your answer is exactly the kind I was looking for as it helped me think about this differently. It also helped me understand SelectMany. Thank you